# autocomplete and multiple function using ajax in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I am new to laravel framework. I want to complete a important task in my app.
In that app they have modules like invoices,quotes,payment,customers. for particular customers they have multiple invoices with status of sent and partially paid.

[image]

Here is the receipt page, on type of customer name it will get autosuggestion from customer table. Onclick of cutomer name it will get invoice details from (invoice table) based on customer id,and need to show on table below that customer name textbox, onclick of table invoice it will open modal which means if the particular customer has unpaid invoice they need to record payment else proceed with normal receipt creation.

I try the code like this, But I am not getting proper output please anyone help me to get out of this issue.

```
  <input type="text" name="customername" required="required"  id="cust" placeholder="Customer Name" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12 typeahead"/>

   $( function() {

    $( "#cust" ).autocomplete({      
      //source: "http://www.duminex.com/client/search",
      source: "{{route('search.client')}}",
      select: function( event, ui ) {

        get_invoices(ui.item.id);

        $('#id').val(ui.item.id);
        $('#clientAddress').val(ui.item.address);
      }

    });
  } );

function get_invoices(client_id)
{
      $.ajax({
    method: 'GET', 
    url: "{{route('client.details')}}"
  }).done(function(data){
        alert(data);
    });

}
```

routes

```
Route::get('/client/search',[

  'uses'=>'ClientsController@search',
  'as'=>'search.client'
]);

Route::get('/client/search2', 'ClientsController@search2')->name('client.details');
```

Controller

```
public function search(Request $request)

    {   
        $s= Input::get('term');
        $clients = Client::select("id" ,"user_id", "companyname", "companyaddress" , "billingAddress")->where('companyname','like','%'.$s.'%')->where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)->get();
               if(count($clients) == 0){
                                $searchResult[] = "No Item found";
                            }
                            else{
                                foreach ($clients as $key => $value) {

                                    $searchResult[] = ['id' => $value->id, 'value' => $value->companyname , 'email' => $value->companyaddress , 'address' => $value->billingAddress];

                                    }
                            }          

                            return $searchResult;                                                                     
    }

    public function search2(Request $request)

    {   
         $clients = Invoice::select("invoiceNo")->where('status',['sent,Partially paid'])->where('client_id',$request->client_id)->get();
               if(count($clients) == 0){
                                $searchResult[] = "No Item found";
                            }
                            else{
                                foreach ($clients as $key => $value) {
                                    $searchResult[] = ['invoiceNo' => $value->invoiceNo];
                                }
                            }          
                                return $searchResult;
    }
```

Thanks in advance. Please anyone to help me get out of this issue.

Comment: Where you stuck ??

Comment: its not returning any values..,

Comment: Which one not return response, search or search2 function ??

Comment: search2 is not returning.. its returning " no item found "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not passing any data to the ajax so thats why you are not getting any result.
Try below code :

```
function get_invoices(client_id) {
    $.ajax({
        method: 'GET',
        data : {
            client_id: client_id
        },
        url: "{{route('client.details')}}"
    }).done(function(data){
        alert(data);
    });
}
```

Comment: I tried this code ., please check search2 function () now also returns " no items found "

Comment: How to retrieve in controller?

Comment: then why its returning empty value again check the query I tried in search2

Comment: And are you getting the `client_id` in the `get_invoices` function ??

Comment: Console log the `client_id` in the `get_invoices` function. Check its blank or has value

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156159/discussion-between-kavya-shree-and-sk-jajoriya).